# OverflowException or OutOfMemoryException when constructing a huge neural network in Encog

Tags: c#, neural-network, encog

I am trying to construct a simple feedforward neural network for RGB image recognition in Encog in C#. For example, if I run the following code:

```cs
        BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork();
        network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, 60000));
        network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 60000));
        network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), false, 4));
        network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
```

I get a *System.OverflowException* from encog-core-cs.dll, and if I double the neuron count at both places to 120 000, I get a *System.OutOfMemoryException*. Is this simply too big a network for Encog, or am I doing something wrong? But if this is too big, how can I use a reasonably sized image for training, say 200×200? Am I doomed to small pictures?

Comment: Run as 64 bit so you can address more memory.

Comment: @BrandonSeydel I have a 32 bit operating system sadly, so this is not an option, I think.

Comment: @BrandonSeydel But I just had my friend try it on 64 bits (complied also to x64), and it was no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could calculate that on a better machine but you're also doing it  wrong. Don't use every single pixel as input resulting in this huge architecture. Approaches operating on the complete raw data usually take really small scaled-down images (and there are image types you can't scale down to 10x10 whilst keeping all information).

Instead, do some **preprocessing**, e.g. isolate the important parts of the picture, eliminate noise and more importantly: *Extract **features*** which you feed to the NN instead of the raw data. Don't ask me what features to use as it's depending on your problem. There are hundreds of possibilities for image recognition. When the NN operates on proper features, you'll see that not only you'll have smaller layers but the accuracy will go up since the network will never see irrelevant data but start operating on some metadata from the beginning.